# Problem in executing application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hello i have created a sample application in **android using eclipse** IDE

my code was working perfect and i have seen output on emulator

suddenly in eclipse my project seems **with red cross icon** and when i am trying to run application at that time it is showing me following error

```
your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application
```

i have seen my code lots of time and not even single file is having any error message.

How to solve this problem??

Comment: Go to `Windows>>Show View>>Problems`. Here you can check for the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cleaning your project (Project->clean) or try removing the auto-generated files inside the gen folder. I sometimes get errors with R.java that can only be resolved by removing it and letting eclipse recreating it.